# iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, iwlwifi

I have just installed the 16.04 in dual boot with Windows.
The installation was OK, and for a couple of times Ubuntu booted smoothly.
Now, after having chosen Ubuntu at the booting, a black screen appears with the following:

> /dev/sda8: clean 271789/1222992 files, 1952109/4882432 blocks
>
> [  10.015870] tom_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfed40080-0xfed40fff]
>
> [  10.507758] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
>
> Welcome to emergency mode!

I tried to search a bit on the web, but there is nothing so specific, even less clear solutions. Any suggestions please?

EDIT: [here is the Pastebin for the *dmesg* log.](http://pastebin.com/5GQp5Jns)

Also, outputs of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="2605-3DC2" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="8a5f68a4-5a57-4238-93dd-f4b072f0f75e"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c8d98f36-1de8-4327-bc66-f14653f56ce4"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="5CCE72F7CE72C8B2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4d6d4d89-ca38-41b7-ad64-5d7be881f962"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="WINRETOOLS" UUID="EC7AA90F7AA8D81A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="1ecce821-a7c3-4cfb-9d01-a2ce25f1e1aa"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Image" UUID="5254A9E354A9C9D5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7514622b-bfa8-4f31-93cf-7730e289739d"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="DELLSUPPORT" UUID="9C98DECB98DEA2D6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="396ddeed-43e8-4d20-b4b4-b1b910688ac3"
/dev/sda7: UUID="c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="9885e759-1e62-4336-91b4-0997baf71a20"
/dev/sda8: UUID="dd4038ad-17fb-43c6-9528-2a6db31c7371" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c90e1cce-c184-466e-8433-a9816b609c76"
/dev/sda9: UUID="d0114045-d0fa-4128-86eb-1872cf863d4c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f0ab486d-6a10-4345-8798-95334cc379d6"
```

Output of the command `sudo lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 465,7G  0 part /windows
├─sda4   8:4    0   467M  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0  14,5G  0 part
├─sda6   8:6    0   1,1G  0 part
├─sda7   8:7    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda8   8:8    0  18,6G  0 part /
└─sda9   8:9    0 426,9G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

and of the coomand `sudo cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=dd4038ad-17fb-43c6-9528-2a6db31c7371 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=d0114045-d0fa-4128-86eb-1872cf863d4c /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=it_IT.UTF-8  0 0
UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

Here is the screenshot for the command

```
dmseg | grep -i error
dmseg | grep -i warn
```

[image]

and here is the screenshot for the command

> dmseg | grep iwl:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems that need to be answered for this question.

The first and foremost problem is with /etc/fstab. It's been radically changed from standard, and a Windows partition was trying to be mounted at two different mount points at the same time. This caused the computer not to boot, and to halt in emergency mode. Here we comment out BOTH Windows disk mounts, and that got the computer to boot.

In /etc/fstab:

---

## Change this:

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=it_IT.UTF-8  0 0
UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

## To this (just comment out 2 lines):

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e none            swap    sw              0       0
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=it_IT.UTF-8  0 0
UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

Then reboot.
**Success!**

---

Then, to clean up the rest of the messy fstab, we do the following edits.

## Change this:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

## To this:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

## Then delete the last line of fstab that looks like:

```
UUID=2605-3DC2  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

---

## Lastly, change this:

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e none            swap    sw              0       0
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=it_IT.UTF-8  0 0
```

## To this:

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# Can't have two mounts, to two different mount points, at the same time.
# Both of these mounts are wrong.
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=it_IT.UTF-8  0 0
# If you MUST mount this Windows partition, I'd recommend this...
# UUID=5CCE72F7CE72C8B2 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults  0 0

# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c35ada9f-7d1a-4220-8c12-5f69cad3236e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

## Then, in Windows, do these:

If you dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, you must turn off `fast start` and `hibernation` in Windows.

1. Turn off `fast start` in the Power control panel

In power control panel, click on `Change what power button does`

Then choose `Change options that are unavailable`

Uncheck `Fast Start`

2. In an administrative command prompt window, type `powercfg /h off`

Comment: Alright! Now Ubuntu boots! But the same errors still appear after the dual-boot menu... Perhaps that deserves a different thread, but if you can tell me about those errors, and how your changes in `fstab` fixed the problem, it would be great!

Comment: Check my updates to my answer. Also, the first two errors are not critical, if everything works. I *suspect* that the tpm* software could be uninstalled, and the iwlwifi error *could* be fixed with a newer kernel or newer iwlwifi driver.

Comment: ps: maybe upgrade to 16.10 to solve the first two errors.

Comment: If the wireless connects and has reasonable speed, then I doubt that the original error, unsupported splx, is significant. Does it? @heynnema Great detective work and great answer!!!

Comment: Ok, I will follow all of your suggestions. But please, can you tell me what's happening? :)

Comment: I gave an explanation in my latest update to my answer. Did I miss anything? The last edits just clean up a messy fstab, and suggest a Windows partition mount. The windows actions turn off fast start and hibernation... something you have to do if you dual boot.

Comment: Perfect, I am working on it. Do you have any idea how did I mess up the fstab (at which stage of a process, or anything)? Also, how can I know if I NEED to mount Windows partition or not?

Comment: Your Ubuntu installation wasn't a fresh/recent installation that we were led to believe. Somebody made a lot of disk partitions, and tried to add Windows mounts and change efi mounts. I couldn't see any reason to mount the Windows partition, and that's why I left it commented out. I just suggest a more proper Windows mount if you do need it.

Comment: Well, that "somebody" was me... I did partitioning on a Win10 machine. But the problem came after, cause at the beginning the system was booting properly. Just one last thing: why do I need to avoid fast start in Windows?

Comment: Fast start and hibernation create a hibernation file that can cause Ubuntu not to mount the disk at boot time (an unclean file system, as far as Ubuntu is concerned)... somewhat similar to the problem that you experienced when you had TWO mounts for your Windows partition. It could also cause corruption on Windows if you were to try and fix this using `ntfsfix` from Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you 100% running now? Consider upgrading to 16.10 to hopefully solve the remaining error messages.